# How can I use nested accordions correctly?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have recently started to do some web programming. So yes I'm a beginner and I hope I don't get bashed for this, probably trivial problem. I've stumbled upon this awesome tutorial for accordions, using CSS and jQuery, that I'd like to use on my web page. My questions are:

1. How can I show first accordion as always active? (display:block; is not really working. When clicked upon loading the page it closes and opens that Accordion 1)
2. How to do nested accordions correctly?

Here's the [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVbJYX).

```js
  
  
$(document).ready(function() {
        function close_accordion_section() {
            $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
      
            $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
        }
     
        $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
            // Grab current anchor value
            var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
     
            if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
                close_accordion_section();
            }else {
                close_accordion_section();
     
                // Add active class to section title
                $(this).addClass('active');
                // Open up the hidden content panel
                $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
            }
     
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```css
    /*----- Accordion -----*/
        .accordion, .accordion * {
            box-sizing:border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
         -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        }
         
        .accordion {
            overflow:hidden;
            box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
            border-radius:3px;
         -moz-border-radius:3px;
         -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            background:#f9cf96;
         color:#9d3528;
        }
         
        /*----- Section Titles -----*/
        .accordion-section-title {
            width:100%;
            padding:15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;
            background:#f9cf96;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
            /* Type */
            font-size:1.200em;
            color:#9d3528;
         text-decoration:none;
        }
         
        .accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
            background:#f2a843;
            /* Type */
            text-decoration:none;
        }
         
        .accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
            border-bottom:none;
        }
         
        /*----- Section Content -----*/
        .accordion-section-content {
            padding:15px;
            display:none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
<div class="accordion-section">
<a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Accordion 1</a>
<div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content" style="display:block;">
<p style="text-indent:20px;">Some text here...</p>
                         
<a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Nested Accordion 1.1</a>
<div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
<p>Some text here and photo gallery.</p>
</div><!--end .accordion-section-content-nested-->
                          
</div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
</div><!--end .accordion-section-->
</div><!--end .accordion-->
```

Comment: Check this link.! hope this is what you needed.! http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Nested-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-multiAccordion/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind. I was just hoping someone would do their magic on this code that I've posted already. And a few 'whys' and 'hows' along the way would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your effort. I'll check out thoroughly that example and hopefully be able to implement some changes into my code.

Comment: @LuckyBastard that's actually not why SO exists. Everybody here is more then happy to help, but in the sense to learn you how to do stuff, and help you finding solutions on problems. But "do their magic" sounds like free programming. The goal is to help you to do it yourself. If you do not want or cannot do that, SO Jobs is a better place for you ;) So if you have a specific question, no problem, but do not dump code and sit back.